# Programmatically change the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion attributes

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, versioninfo

During a setup creation process, I am planning to do the following (within a [C# Script](http://www.csscript.net/)):

1. Read the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute values of one DLL.
2. Iterate all DLLs and executables in the project and apply those version to their `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute values.

Question now is: **How to do step 2?**

I successfully can do step 1, but for step 2 I don't see a real start point. What I probably have to do is to use some native P/Invoke methods since the attributes directly modify the version information resource information of a DLL/executable.

Any hints on this?

Comment: If you have access to the sources, take the [advice from Graviton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550249/programmatically-change-the-assemblyversion-and-assemblyfileversion-attributes/1550251#1550251) If you don't, you might be in trouble. Possibly you can disassemble with ILDASM and reassemble with ILASM. But this won't work out for strong-named assemblies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why don't you, during build process, read the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` of one DLL, and save it back to other csproject's `AssemblyInfo.cs`, only then compile it?

As a matter of fact, I don't know whether it is possible to modify the DLL file directly, without resorting to something fanciful.

Or alternatively, make sure that all your DLLs share one common `AssemblyInfo.cs`. You can do this by adding the `AssemblyInfo.cs` as "Add As Link" when you add a new item in csproject. In this way when you do a compilation, all the DLLs will share the same `AssemblyInfo.cs`, and thus output the same `AssemblyVersion`.

Comment: yes, that would be **much** easier! Set the version numbers straight at build time, e.g. using a continuous integration build server

Comment: That would be the right way, changing the compiled files break clean information line between code and binaries.

Comment: Thank you very much, I do like the idea of sharing the AssemblyInfo.cs file!

Comment: Not a good idea to share the same AssemblyInfo.cs - if your DLLs has ComVisible, then you can't differentiate GUID and other info on assembly

Comment: Just to remind the `AssemblyInfo.cs` contains not just the File & Assembly Version info but other information like ["Title","Description", "Company", "Product","Copyright","TradeMark"] and they cannot share the same name.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I created a T4 template for changing the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion.  I called the template Assembly.tt, and made it a linked file (when you add it choose Add Link, instead of Add).  All my assemblies pull in the linked Assembly.tt file.

You can then run the T4 template from one location and it will update all the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersions.  You don't have to call the file AssemblyInfo.cs for the information to be pulled into your dlls.

The code for the Assembly.tt file is:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true" #>
// 
// This code was generated by a tool. Any changes made manually will be lost
// the next time this code is regenerated.
// 

using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.<#= this.RevisionYear #>.<#= this.RevisionNumber #>.<#= this.RevisionTime #>")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("4.<#= this.RevisionYear #>.<#= this.RevisionNumber #>.<#= this.RevisionTime #>")]
<#+
    int RevisionYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;
    int RevisionNumber = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year,1,1)).TotalDays;
    int RevisionTime = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day)).TotalMinutes;
#>
```

The output of the T4 template above will be:

```
// 
// This code was generated by a tool. Any changes made manually will be lost
// the next time this code is regenerated.
// 

using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.2016.284.1066")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("4.2016.284.1066")]
```

Comment: This actually will work as an answer to dynamically change the dll version on compile time, i wonder why this is not marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `[AssemblyVersion()]` and `[AssemblyFileVersion()]` both accepts a constant `string` as parameter.

So I can create a `static class` with a `const` `string` in the current assembly, and can supply it to these `attributes` as parameters as below

```cs
    public static class App
    {
        public const string Version = "1.0.0.1";
    }
```

and update the `AssemblyInfo.cs` as

```cs
[assembly: AssemblyVersion(App.Version)]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(App.Version)]
```

This is an alternative suggestion then the automation/trick suggested by **@Kelly R** and **@Gravtion** above.

---

### Update 1 - Using `T4` template

In case you want to go for `T4 template` as @KellyR suggested the following can help you with the version:

```cs
private string Version()
{
    DateTime START = new DateTime(2021,2, 14); //StartDate
    DateTime NOW = DateTime.Now;
    int numMonths = (int)(NOW.Subtract(START).Days / (365.25 / 12));
    int Major = numMonths / 12;
    int Minor = numMonths % 12;
    int Build = (int)DateTime.Now.Day;
    string Revision = $"{(int)DateTime.Now.Hour}{DateTime.Now.Minute}";
    
    return $"{Major}.{Minor}.{Build}.{Revision}";
}
```

The `START` stores the start date of the project which is used to calculate the number of months passed till now. Then it's dividing the `numMonths` by 12 to get the number of year passed(*considering it as `Major` version*) and keeps the remaining months as `Minor` version then the current day as `Build` and hour + Minutes as `Revision`.

With that every time you build you will get the latest version of your product.

This can also be used in the `T4 template` as follows:

```cs
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ template debug="true" language="C#" hostspecific="false" #>

using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("<#= NewVersion() #>")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("<#= NewVersion() #>")]



<#+
    private string NewVersion()
    {
        DateTime START = new DateTime(2021,2, 14); //StartDate
        DateTime NOW = DateTime.Now;
        int numMonths = (int)(NOW.Subtract(START).Days / (365.25 / 12));
        int Major = numMonths / 12;
        int Minor = numMonths % 12;
        int Build = (int)DateTime.Now.Day;
        string Revision = $"{(int)DateTime.Now.Hour}{DateTime.Now.Minute}";
    
        return $"{Major}.{Minor}.{Build}.{Revision}";

    }
    //Started On = 12-5-2021;
    
    
#>
```

Just remember to comment `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` in `AssemblyInfo.cs` when using it as `T4 template`.

```cs
//[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

---

### Update 2 - Using MsBuild to rewrite `AssemblyInfo.cs` with `regx`

We can also change the assembly version by editing the `.csproj` file by adding the following:

```xml
  <Target Name="AssemblyVersion" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <AssemblyInfo>Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs</AssemblyInfo>
      <AssemblyInfoContent>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(AssemblyInfo)))</AssemblyInfoContent>
      <VersionRegex>(\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*AssemblyVersion\(\s*"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.)(\d+)("\)\s*\]))</VersionRegex>
      <BuildAndRevisionRegex>(\d+\.\d+")</BuildAndRevisionRegex>
      <AssemblyVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match('$(AssemblyInfoContent)', '$(VersionRegex)'))</AssemblyVersion>

      <!-- New AssemblyVersion Block -->
      <NowTime>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Year)</NowTime>
      <MajorVersion>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(NowTime), 2023).ToString("0"))</MajorVersion>
      <MinorBuildRevision>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("M.d.hhm"))</MinorBuildRevision>
      
      <AssemblyVersion>[assembly: AssemblyVersion("$(MajorVersion).$(MinorBuildRevision)")]</AssemblyVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Write New AssemblyVersion Block to AssemblyInfo.cs file -->
    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(AssemblyInfo)" Lines="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($(AssemblyInfoContent), $(VersionRegex), $(AssemblyVersion)))" Overwrite="true" />
  </Target>
```

What it does is it reads the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file and replaces the `AssemblyVersion` using `regularexpressions` and `DateTime` values.

Look for the below code where we can change the value `2023` to the any current/past year to generate the `MajorVersion`.

```xml
<MajorVersion>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(NowTime), 2023).ToString("0"))</MajorVersion>
<MinorBuildRevision>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("M.d.hhm"))</MinorBuildRevision>
```

The `MajorVersion` is calculated as `DateTime.Now.Year - 2023` so expect it to be `0` if the first release year is `2023`. The `Minor`,`Build` & `Revision` are dynamic in nature as it is derived with the `DateTime` component giving the value in format `"M.d.hhm"`

```cs
DateTime.Now.ToString("M.d.hhm")
```

At the time of this update it is giving a value `8.23.0458` and with the major version it becomes `0.8.23.0458`

---

### Update 3 - creating `NewVersion.cs` with `AssemblyFileVersion`

There is one more better way is to generate a new `NewVersion.cs` with  `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute. Which can be achieved with `WriteCodeFragment` as:

```xml
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <NowTime>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Year)</NowTime>
      <MajorVersion>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(NowTime), 2023).ToString())</MajorVersion>
      <NewVersion>$(MajorVersion).$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("M.d.hhm"))</NewVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <AssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyFileVersion">
        <_Parameter1>$(NewVersion)</_Parameter1>
      </AssemblyAttributes>
    </ItemGroup>
    <WriteCodeFragment AssemblyAttributes="@(AssemblyAttributes)"
        Language="C#"
       OutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
       OutputFile="NewVersion.cs">
      <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="Compile" />
      <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="FileWrites" />
    </WriteCodeFragment>
  </Target>
```

Just add the above to `csproj` file at the end and  comment the `AssemblyFileVersion` in `AssemblyInfo.cs` else the compiler will complain for duplicate attribute.

This will create a `NewVersion.cs` to `obj/Debug` folder and will use it for compilation and keep updating the file with a new version.