# Updating the version of a C# program

Tags: c#

I have a simple C# program where I need to update the version of it through the program (not manually. i.e. via a user input or so). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Version of a program is directly linked to the assembly (exe) you deploy. I can see no use in modifying version by the user who executes the program.
Or you want to modify another assembly's version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550249/programmatically-change-the-assemblyversion-and-assemblyfileversion-attributes

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically install a new version of your program?

Comment: Please mark as answered,based on which you find is the correct answer.This may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download reflector.net , it has a self update facility.Basically you can add code to your program to check a url or webservice that send a message that you have a new version number.Then you prompt the user telling him that there is an update and on a different thread download the update,once you get the flag that the download is complete you unzip the update and then run another exe that will update your application or and you can shutdown you application in between.....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is the version settings for a build? Right click your project-> properties -> assembly information.

Or are you looking for a way to do this through code?