# Change assembly version of another .EXE

Tags: c#, assemblyversions

How to change from one project, assembly version of another project (.exe)? I have source for both projects.

Comment: Why would you want to just change the assembly versions, they are used for a particular reason and incremented for changes made in the assembly

Comment: i develop an updater for my app.. My boss dont want to use XML file with version instead getting assembly version. I dont know why (may be some can me explain reasons?)? And when i update my app, i need to increment assembly version of main executable file from updater.

Comment: If that file is not modified/patched, you should not change it via your updater. About how to display version numbers, you may learn from Visual Studio, which uses registry keys, instead of the one embedded in the dll/exe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I once [had a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550249/programmatically-change-the-assemblyversion-and-assemblyfileversion-attributes), the best answers I got was to [share an `AssemblyVersion.cs` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550249/programmatically-change-the-assemblyversion-and-assemblyfileversion-attributes/1550251#1550251) across the projects.

In my scenario this was a very good solution.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: @Drazisil Cheers. Glad you liked the effort.