# Dynamic Versioning

Tags: c#, vb.net, assemblyfileversion

I have a situation where i want the versioning to be dynamic at build time.

Version Pattern: `<year>.<month>.<day>.<hhmm>`

But i have read where the String value used in the Attribute is reparsed at compile time.

Any advise on how to get this dynamic versioning completed?

Ideal situation:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.0.0.0")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(Year(Now) & "." & Month(Now()) & "." & Day(Now()) & "." & String.format("hhmm", now()))>
```

I know it wont work but should get the point acrossed.

Comment: http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/

Comment: @RobertHarvey so no way to intercept the Version information in Pre-Build?  This sucks as most of the auto-increment for VS2012 assumes wild-card.

Comment: Are you sure the Autobuild plugin doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am building the app, but it will be maintained by the client.  So i am trying to keep the tool add-ins to a minimum, if possible

Comment: Here are two previous answers.  Do these help?

[can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio][1]

[programmatically-change-the-assemblyversion-and-assemblyfileversion-attributes][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550249/programmatically-change-the-assemblyversion-and-assemblyfileversion-attributes

Comment: @DonnyMcCoy Ill review them further tomorrow.  Wish they allowed more pattern designed Versioning than the `Increment(1, 1)` styled versioning.

Comment: You could use a T4 file to regenerate the the file containing the buildnumber on every build.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [MsbuildCommunityTasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/downloads) to generate the build number and to customize the assembly file version on pre-build time.

- Download the zip at [MsbuildCommunityTasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/downloads)
- Unzip to the folder [SolutionFolder]\MsBuildExtensions\MSBuildCommunityTasks
- Add the sample below on your project (csproj), just after the Microsoft.CSharp.Targets import.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\MsBuildExtensions\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>  
    <My-PropertiesDir>Properties</My-PropertiesDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Time Format="yyyy.MM.dd.HHmm">
      <Output TaskParameter="FormattedTime" PropertyName="My-VersionNumber" />
    </Time>
    <Message Text="Building $(My-VersionNumber) ...">
    </Message>
    <ItemGroup>
      <My-AssemblyInfo Include="$(My-PropertiesDir)\AssemblyVersionInfo.cs" />
      <Compile Include="@(My-AssemblyInfo)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(My-PropertiesDir)" />
    <AssemblyInfo OutputFile="@(My-AssemblyInfo)"
          CodeLanguage="CS"
          AssemblyFileVersion="$(My-VersionNumber)"
          AssemblyInformationalVersion="$(My-VersionNumber)"
          Condition="$(My-VersionNumber) != '' "
          />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Delete Files="@(My-AssemblyInfo)" />
  </Target>
```

- Wipe the AssemblyFileVersion attribute from your AssemblyInfo.cs. It will be generated at build time.
- You'll see the version number being printed on the console when you build. The generated file is deleted on the AfterBuild target, to keep your source control clean.

  *BeforeBuild:*

  Building 2013.01.14.1016 ...
   Created AssemblyInfo file "Properties\AssemblyVersionInfo.cs".

  (...)

  *AfterBuild:*

  Deleting file "Properties\AssemblyVersionInfo.cs".
- If you want do this to many projects with less msbuild code, it will be necessary to create a customized build script to wrap up your solution.

Comment: I would assume that this applies to VB as well?  I flip between CS and VB, just want to make sure i can use the same DevEnv build standard between the two languages.

Comment: Yes, it works fine with VB. You just have to adjust the 'AssemblyInfo'  task parameters (CodeLanguage="VB") and adjust the properties My-PropertiesDir and My-AssemblyInfo accordingly.

Comment: ill have to get this installed on my dev-top....as client computer is locked down to where i cant install anything without requests ;)

Comment: Good luck on your task. MSBuild Community Tasks is like a swiss knife for building .Net projects. I'm pretty sure that you will like it. ^^

Comment: always like new tools, especially those that allow for user customization for what they need, instead of what MS thinks they need ;)