# Set AssemblyName.Version Property

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

The MSDN description for the AssemblyName.Version property state that it "Gets or sets the major, minor, build, and revision numbers of the assembly."

I have tried to set the assembly version but it doesn't work. I set the version of an assembly on one line and try to get it  on the  next line and that property still contains the previous version.

Unfortunately, the example on the MSDN page only shows how to set the version while building a new assembly but I would like to use this method to increment the version number of an existing assembly.

Does anyone know why this happens? Maybe, I am missing something obvious but this seems strange.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550249/programmatically-change-the-assemblyversion-and-assemblyfileversion-attributes

Comment: You can manually do the changes in the AssemblyInfo.cs of every project to have the desired version number

Comment: Why do you want to change the assembly version at runtime ? It will just change back the next time you build

Answer (score 1):

Check out the article:

[Automatically update version number](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31236/How-To-Update-Assembly-Version-Number-Automaticall)

It use the utility, `AssemblyInfoUtil.exe` to do the changes dynamically

Another interesting article which does the same work by modifying the IL

[Modify assembly version numbers](http://oncoding.blogspot.in/2012/04/net-assembly-version-numbers.html)