# T4 template not changing and showing the assembly value

Tags: c#

I am having an project in dot net 2.0 framework build. I wanted to change it's assembly copyright attribute while building the application. For that I have used T4 template as per the guidance by below two links

1. [Dynamically display current year in assembly info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196312/dynamically-display-current-year-in-assembly-info)
2. [Programmatically change the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550249/programmatically-change-the-assemblyversion-and-assemblyfileversion-attributes)

I tried changing the code but it doesn't have any effect at all.[![

```html
<#@ template language="VB" #>
<#@ output extension=".vb" #>
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection

<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Test Assembly Copyright <#=DateTime.Now#>")>
```

[image]

Comment: **Why** are you targeting .NET Framework 2.0? It's obsolete and doesn't even run on Windows 7 (where the minimum is .NET Framework 3.5), let alone Windows 10 or Windows 11.

Comment: I am not targeting dot net 2.0 framework my project already has build with this framework. I can not change all the files because it cost me ton of effort to change.

Comment: But you wrote "I am having an project in dot net 2.0 framework build"